# Rails: Interpolation in an ActiveRecord Relationship Declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, interpolation

I have a concern that dynamically creates relationship declarations:

```
has_many :revisions, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "#{class.name}::Revision"
```

Note that the `class_name` is trying to interpolate `class.name`. Unfortunately, Rails sputters on this. It also sputters on:

```
has_many :revisions, dependent: :destroy, class_name: class.name+"::Revision"
```

I'm assuming there must a way to get Rails to recognize string manipulations in the middle of a relationship declaration, but I'm unsure how to do so.

Comment: What error are you having? are you aware that class in this case is `Class`, self is the class of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `self.name`

```
has_many :revisions, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "#{self.name}::Revision"
```